# Prove the following language is regular by using the Myhill-Nerode Relation

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, regular-language

$w=\{w | \text{w begins with a 1 and ends with a 0}\}$

Let $A_1\{w|\text{w begins with a 1 and ends with a 0}\}$
  $A_2=\{w|\text{w begins with a 0 and ends with a 0}\}$
$A_3=\{w|\text{w begins with a 0 and ends with a 1}\}$
$A_4=\{w|\text{w begins with a 1 and ends with a 0}\}$

1) Any $x,y\in A_1$ are related by $R_{A_1}$ because let's take any string z that ends with a 0. If we take any $x,y\in A_1$ then $xz \in A_1$ and $yz \in A_1$

2) Any x,y in $A_2$ are related by $R_L$ because if we take any $z\in \sum^*$, $xz \notin A_1$ and $yz \notin A_1$ since every string in $A_2$ starts with a 0.

3) $A_3$ same reason as 2)

4) $A_4$ Same reason as 1

And we know that $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 = \sum^*$. Therefore, $A_1$ is regular

How does that look?

Comment: For part 1, you would also need to show the other case where $z$ ends with $1$ (in which case both $xz \notin A_1$ and $yz \notin A_1$ so that still works).

Comment: Also, to show that they are equivalence classes, you would also need to show that for each $x_i \in A_i$ and $x_j \in A_j$ with $i \neq j$ that $(x_i,x_j) \notin R_L$. However, at most, you would end up combining some of the equivalence classes which would still leave the number of equivalence classes finite, so that's not so much of an issue.