# Understanding Context Free Grammars

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I have the following production rules
\begin{align*}
R\rightarrow XRX|S \\ S \rightarrow aTb|bTa\\ T\rightarrow XTX|X|\epsilon\\X\rightarrow a|b
\end{align*}

True or false $T \rightarrow^* T$

I don't see any way T can get to just T by a series of rules transformations.

Comment: It is false. Either $T$ will go to the empty string or $T$ will be forced to go to a string that contains the terminal symbols $a$ or $b$.

Comment: How do you define $\rightarrow^*$?

Comment: I'm guessing he's defining it to mean "there exists a sequence of applications of the production rules that transform the left hand side to the right hand side".

Comment: @benguin The key detail is whether the star denotes the *reflexive* transitive closure (as it usually does) or not.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi benguin's definition is right, but the book says the statement is true.

Comment: How does the book define $\rightarrow^*$?  Does a sequence of length 0 satisfy the definition?

Comment: The book says the statement is true. I corrected my claim. I will provide the definition in a minute.

Comment: If u, v, and w are strings of variables and terminals, and A → w is a rule of the grammar, we say that uAv yields uwv, written uAv ⇒ uwv. Say that u derives v, written u ∗ ⇒ v, if u = v or if a sequence u1,u2,...,uk exists for k ≥ 0 and u⇒ u1 ⇒ u2 ⇒ ... ⇒ uk ⇒ v.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Good point regarding the possibility of $0$ length sequences.

Comment: However the book says that the following can't be true. $T \rightarrow T$

Comment: According to the definition, since $T = T$, then $T \to ^* T$.

Comment: This agrees with the standard definition.  (See, for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Repetitive_rule_application).)  I would have thought that $k$ should be greater than or equal to $1$, not $0$, given that the case $u=v$ is covered separately.

Comment: Ok and why can't $T \rightarrow T$ be true? What is the definition of just $\rightarrow$?

Comment: The symbol $\to$ means that it is possible to transform the left hand side to the right hand side using exactly one application of one of the production rules.

Comment: As @benguin noted, every production $P$ such that $T \rightarrow^+P$ (one or more rules are applied) contains terminals, which can't be eliminated. In general, rules like $T \rightarrow T$ are never needed and  $T \rightarrow^* T$ is always true.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I need help with this exercise. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2169753/prove-the-following-language-is-regular-by-using-the-myhill-nerode-relation